# Speed up file access on home network

Tags: router, home-networking

I have two PCs (Windows 7 Ultimate) and a Mac running Windows 7 using VMware Fusion on my home network tied together using a WRN1000 NETGEAR Router.

On one of the PCs I have a set of files (MYOB .myo).  These use a data source to access the data in the files.

Operations (reading, writing) to the .myo on the PC which hosts the files is fine but on the other two it is painfully slow/unreliable. I am wondering what I can do to speed this up.

Some ideas I have are:

1. Turn off the Windows Firewall on all the Windows installations on the home network
2. Buy another router, specifically a router which I can connect a USB flash drive on the back where I can put the .myo files and all the PCs can access the files from the USB flash drive on the router (does this speed things up?)

Any advice greatly appreciated on how I can speed up this access to data.

Comment: USB storage on a router will most likely not be faster.

Comment: Turning off the firewall will also not help.

Comment: Which devices are wired and which wireless?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz all the devices are wired.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to use Virtual Desktop and run the application on the host machine over the network.

Have you since considered upgrading to AccountRight Live (ARL). You could either upload an upgraded `.myo` file into the cloud or you could use the network install of ARL which was developed to allow users to work in the way you describe (There is however no MAC support for ARL but you could use Parallels to run Windows on the MAC). ARL also comes with a REST-based API which is the same for the desktop as it is in the cloud.